# What is calculated earlier in vector element assignment

Tags: c++, c++17

If i have that line of code:

```
vec[f1(x, y)] = f2(a, b);
```

What would compiler run first: `f1(x, y)` or `f2(a, b)`?

Comment: Handy reading: [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). point 20 is particularly relevant.

Comment: You can test this yourself. It won't take a minute.

Comment: @WaisKamal Before C++17, that wouldn't work since the behavior was implementation defined.

Comment: @NathanOliver which is why I'm thankful this is tagged [tag:c++17]!

Comment: @WaisKamal: That would be a complacent approach when it comes to C++.

Comment: If you care about the order you probably shouldn't leave it up to the compiler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`f2(a, b)` is computed first, per [[expr.ass#1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1)<sup>1</sup> (emphasis is mine):

> [...] In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.
> **The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.** [...]

**Note 1:** that this is only true for C++17 onward, for previous standards, the order of evaluation was implementation-specific.

**Note 2:** This is not specific to vector item assignment (there is no such thing in the standard), any assignment (or compound assignment) follows these rules.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is from the C++17 latest draft (section 8.18), but the wording has not changed (yet), see [[expr.ass#1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1) in the latest draft.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure the order of evaluation was implementation-defined prior to C++17? Upvoted in good faith though.

Comment: @user4581301 Clarified - I cannot find an HTML version of the C++17 standard online, so I kept the latest draft but I checked the C++17 latest draft and it was the same wording, the section numbering was changed.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm sure it was not defined, but you mean maybe it was UB? I'm not 100% sure, I will check.

Comment: Closest link to C++17 I have is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/

Comment: @Holt: It wasn't UB (as that would mean the entire program behaviour was undefined). You just had to be mindful that the order of the function calls was arbitrary.

Comment: I think the C++14 standard may have said that it was *indeterminately sequenced*, but AFAIK implementations normally picked once approach and used that always, i.e either `E1` or `E2` was always evaluated first.

Comment: And Almost C++14, just to complete the set: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/ (Relevant text: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr#ass-1)

Comment: @PeteBecker   I suspect the term "unspecified" (in the sense in which that term is used by the standards) is relevant here.

Comment: @Peter — in less technical contexts such as here, people often want to say “it’s up to the implementation and different implementations do different things”, and that’s when they reach for “implementation defined”. “Unspecified” doesn’t convey that different implementations **in fact** do different things. That’s why I use and recommend “implementation specific”.